# How to catch a particular name assignment?

Tags: python, variable-assignment, assign

(Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48722144/7032856)):

One can override the `__setattr__` magic method for an object to have additional instructions when an `attribute` of an object is set. As in:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, attribute=None):
        object.__init__(self)
        self.attribute = attribute


    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self.__dict__[name] = value
        if name == 'attribute':
            print("attribute's value is modified to {}.".format(
                                                        self.attribute))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_obj = MyClass(True)
    while True:
        my_obj.attribute = input()
```

- How can I catch a particular name assignment in the current script
  without using classes(specifically to call a method with more
  instructions)?

```
def b_is_modified():
    print("b is modified!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = 3
    b = 4
    b = 5
```

How to call `b_is_modified` when `b` is assigned a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48722160/7032856):

It ***can't*** be catched(at least in python level).

Simple name assignment(`b = 4`), as oppposed to object attribute assignment (`object.b = 5`), is a *fundamental* operation of the language itself. It's not implemented in terms of a lower-level operation that one can override. Assignment just *is*.

Answer (score 2):

I think the other answer by Nae sums it up; I'm not aware of any built-in mechanisms in the Python languages to detect assignments, so if you want an interrupt-like event system to trigger upon assignment I don't know if it's feasible.

However, you seem quiet determined to get a way to "detect" assignment, so I want to describe an approach that might get you closer than nothing.

There are the built-in functions `globals()` and `locals()` that creates dictionary of variables in global and local scope respectively. (They, in additon to `vars()` are further explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7969953/1144382)).

A noteworthy point is that `locals()` will behave differently if called from inside a function:

> If `locals()` is called **inside** a function it constructs a dictionary of the function namespace as of that moment and returns it -- any further name assignments are **not** reflected in the returned dictionary, and any assignments **to** the dictionary are **not** reflected in the actual local namespace
>
> If `locals()` is called **outside** a function it returns the actual dictionary that is the current namespace. Further changes to the namespace **are** reflected in the dictionary, and changes to the dictionary **are** reflected in the namespace:

Here is a "hacky" way to detect changes to variables:

```
def b_is_modified():
    print("b is modified!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    old = locals().get('b')

    a = 3
    b = 4
    b = 5

    new = locals().get('b')
    if id(new) != id(old) and new is not None:
        b_is_modified()
```

This is nothing else but an (obfuscated?) way of checking if the value of `b` has changed from one point in execution to another, and there is no callback event or trigger action that detects it. However, if you want to expand on this approach continue reading.

The rest of the answer explains how to check for changes in `b` by rewriting it to something like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    monitor = ScopeVariableMonitor(locals())

    a = 3
    b = 4
    monitor.compare_and_update()  # Detects creation of a and b
    b = 5
    monitor.compare_and_update()  # Detects changes to b
```

The following will "detect" any changes to the variables, and I've also included an example where it's used inside a function, to reiterate that then the dictionary returned from `locals()` does not update.

The `ScopeVariableMonitor`-class is just an example, and combines the code in one place. In essence, it's comparing changes to the existence and values of variables between `update()`s.

```
class ScopeVariableMonitor:
    def __init__(self, scope_vars):
        self.scope_vars = scope_vars  # Save a locals()-dictionary instance
        self.old = self.scope_vars.copy()  # Make a shallow copy for later comparison

    def update(self, scope_vars=None):
        scope_vars = scope_vars or self.scope_vars
        self.old = scope_vars.copy()  # Make new shallow copy for next time

    def has_changed(self, var_name):
        old, new = self.old.get(var_name), self.scope_vars.get(var_name)
        print('{} has changed: {}'.format(var_name, id(old) != id(new)))

    def compare_and_update(self, var_list=None, scope_vars=None):
        scope_vars = scope_vars or self.scope_vars
        # Find new keys in the locals()-dictionary
        new_variables = set(scope_vars.keys()).difference(set(self.old.keys()))
        if var_list:
            new_variables = [v for v in new_variables if v in var_list]
        if new_variables:
            print('\nNew variables:')
            for new_variable in new_variables:
                print(' {} = {}'.format(new_variable, scope_vars[new_variable]))

        # Find changes of values in the locals()-dictionary (does not handle deleted vars)
        changed_variables = [var_name for (var_name, value) in self.old.items() if
                             id(value) != id(scope_vars[var_name])]
        if var_list:
            changed_variables = [v for v in changed_variables if v in var_list]
        if changed_variables:
            print('\nChanged variables:')
            for var in changed_variables:
                print('  Before: {} = {}'.format(var, self.old[var]))
                print(' Current: {} = {}\n'.format(var, scope_vars[var], self.old[var]))
        self.update()
```

The "interesting" part is the `compare_and_update()`-method, if provided with a list of variables names, e.g. `['a', 'b']`, it will only look for changes to those to variables. The `scope_vars`-parameter is required when inside the function scope, but not in the global scope; for reasons explained above.

```
def some_function_scope():
    print('\n --- Now inside function scope --- \n')
    monitor = ScopeVariableMonitor(locals())
    a = 'foo'
    b = 42
    monitor.compare_and_update(['a', 'b'], scope_vars=locals())
    b = 'bar'
    monitor.compare_and_update(scope_vars=locals())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    monitor = ScopeVariableMonitor(locals())
    var_list = ['a', 'b']
    a = 5
    b = 10
    c = 15
    monitor.compare_and_update(var_list=var_list)

    print('\n *** *** *** \n')  # Separator for print output

    a = 10
    b = 42
    c = 100
    d = 1000
    monitor.has_changed('b')
    monitor.compare_and_update()

    some_function_scope()
```

Output:

```
New variables:
 a = 5
 b = 10

 *** *** *** 

b has changed: True

New variables:
 d = 1000

Changed variables:
  Before: b = 10
 Current: b = 42

  Before: a = 5
 Current: a = 10

  Before: c = 15
 Current: c = 100


 --- Now inside function scope --- 

New variables:
 a = foo
 b = 42

Changed variables:
  Before: b = 42
 Current: b = bar
```

### Conclusion

My answer is just a more general way of doing:

```
b = 1
old_b = b

# ...

if b != old_b:
    print('b has been assigned to')
```

The dictionary from `locals()` will hold **everything** that is a variable, including functions and classes; not just "simple" variables like your `a`, `b` and `c`.

In the implementation above, checks between "old" and "new" values are done by comparing the `id()` of the *shallow* copy of before with `id()` of the current value. This approach allows for comparison of ANY value, because the `id()` will return the virtual memory address, but this is assumable far from a good, general comparison scheme.

I'm curious to what you want to achieve and why you want to detect assignments: if you share your goal then perhaps I can think of another way to reach it in another way.

Comment: I wanted to mimic the way `__setattr__` can be overridden for an object, for global variable assignment, as opposed to `object.attribute` assignment.

Comment: I see. Was there a particular reason for why you couldn't make a class, or were you just curious?

Comment: I was just curious. I wanted to make an example for something, and for simplicity I didn't want to create a class.